# Can't return response without escape symbol

Tags: spring-boot, gson

spring boot 2.5

```
    @PostMapping("/cart/product")
        public Response addProduct(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payloadMap) {
            logger.info("addProduct: payloadMap: " + payloadMap);
            String userName = payloadMap.get("user_name").toString();
            final Product product = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(payloadMap.get("product"), Product.class);
            int quantity = (int) payloadMap.get("quantity");
            Cart findCart = cartRepository.findByUsername(userName);
            if (findCart == null) {
                Cart cart = new Cart();
                cart.setCreated(new Date());
                cart.setUsername(userName);
                cart.addProduct(product, quantity);
                cartRepository.save(cart);
                logger.info("addProduct: success_add_product_to_new_cart: " + cart);
                return ResponseService.getSuccessResponse(GsonUtil.gson.toJson(cart));
            } else {
                findCart.addProduct(product, quantity);
                logger.info("addProduct: before_save_exist_cart: " + findCart);
                cartRepository.save(findCart);
                logger.info("addProduct: success_add_product_to_exist_cart: " + findCart);
                return ResponseService.getSuccessResponse(GsonUtil.gson.toJson(findCart));
            }
        }

     public static Response getSuccessResponse(String body) {
            Response response = new Response(SUCCESS_CODE, SUCCESS_MESSAGE, body);
            logger.info("getSuccessResponse: response = " + response);
            return response;
        }

    public class Response {
        private int code;
        private String message;
        private String body;

        public Response(int code, String message) {
            this.code = code;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Response(int code, String message, String body) {
            this.code = code;
            this.message = message;
            this.body = body;
        }


public class GsonUtil {
    public static GsonBuilder gsonbuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    public static Gson gson;
    public static JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    static {
        // @Expose -> to exclude specific field when serialize/deserilaize
        gsonbuilder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
                return field.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        gson = gsonbuilder.create();
    }
}
```

Here result:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "Success",
  "body": "{\"id\":127,\"username\":\"admin@admin.com\",\"created\":\"Apr 11, 2020, 10:17:31 PM\",\"productEntities\":[{\"id\":128,\"created\":\"Apr 11, 2020, 10:17:31 PM\",\"quantity\":1,\"product\":{\"id\":129,\"name\":\"product name\",\"description\":\"product description\",\"created\":\"Mar 10, 2020, 10:34:15 PM\",\"price\":11.15,\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"images\":[\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/44444?s\=200x200\&d\=identicon\",\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/33333?s\=200x200\&d\=identicon\"]}}],\"totalAmount\":11.15,\"currency\":\"EUR\"}"
}
```

But I need to return response without escape.
It it possible?

Comment: you can change after json creation

Comment: @AbinashGhosh do you have some example? Thanks

Comment: It's better if you change the type of body to JsonObject, that way it will be generic and you will be able to assign any json object.